# ignore value in curly braces

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

```
public static string ToKebabCase(this string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        return value;

    return Regex.Replace(
                value,
                "(?<!^)([A-Z][a-z]|(?<=[a-z])[A-Z])",
                "-$1",
                RegexOptions.Compiled)
            .Trim()
            .ToLower();
}
```

This method make string

```
"{branchId}/GetUser/{userId}" -> "{branch-id}/-get-user/{user-id}"
```

I need:

```
 "{branchId}/get-user/{userId}"
```

How to *ignore* value in *curly braces*?

Answer (score 1):

This is just an example of "*not everything has to be solved with regex*"

```
public static string ToKebabCase(this string value)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
      return value;

   var list = value.Split('/');
   list[1] = Regex.Replace(list[1], "([A-Z])", "-$1").ToLower();

   return string.Join("/", list).Trim();
}
```

---

A `RegEx` solution might be

```
public static string ToKebabCase(string value)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
      return value;

   return Regex.Replace(value, @"(?<!/)([A-Z])(?![^\{\}]*\})", "-$1").Trim()
}
```

**It reads as follows**

Is not preceded by the `/`

```
(?<!/)
```

Capital Letters

```
([A-Z])
```

Is not within brackets

```
(?![^\{\}]*\})
```

Comment: All variants return {branchid}/get-user/{userid}, but I need {branchId}/get-user/{userId}. Is it possible?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanov you will need the first one, i have updated it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could capture `{branchId}` in group 1,  `Get` in group 2 and `User` in group 3 and `{userId}` in group 4 for your example string with:

[`({[^}]+})(\/[A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+\/)({[^}]+})`](https://regex101.com/r/ROc04i/1)

In the replacement you would use `$1$2-$3$4`

```
public static string ToKebabCase(this string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        return value;

    Regex r1 = new Regex(@"({[^}]+})(\/[A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+\/)({[^}]+})");
    Match match = r1.Match(value);
    if (match.Success) {
        value = String.Format("{0}{1}-{2}{3}", 
            match.Groups[1].Value,
            match.Groups[2].Value.ToLower(),
            match.Groups[3].Value.ToLower(),
            match.Groups[4].Value
        );           
    }
    return value;
}
```

[Demo output C#](http://rextester.com/WVK6102)